# Why does shift(1) return a number with brackets around it, but shift() does not?

Tags: ruby, arrays, shift

So for example:

```
def ding_dong()
    p @arr.shift(1)
    p @arr.shift
end
```

If I call this with:

```
ding_dong([0,1,2,3,4])
```

Why does the first puts return "[0]" and the second return "1" without the brackets?

Comment: It will not return what you describe. It will just raise an argument error.

Comment: The documentation clearly states that your observations will happen.  Your code, however, will produce undefined method `shift' for nil:NilClass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation on [Array#shift](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-shift):

> shift → obj or nil
>
> shift(n) → new_ary
>
> Returns the first element of self and removes it (shifting all other elements down by one). Returns nil if the array is empty.
>
> *If a number n is given, returns an array of the first n elements* (or less) just like array.slice!(0, n) does.

Try using `shift(0)` and `shift(2)` and see what happens.

When accepting *any* number, it makes most sense to return an Array, even when the result is a single element. Otherwise the caller would have to write special-case code for when n was 0 or 1 (or when there was 0 or 1 sliced elements).